# Prevent UITableViewCell from scrolling under viewForHeaderInSection

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview

I have a fairly complicated UIViewController with a custom UITableView instantiating on top of a Visual Effect & UIImageView. In order to keep the beautiful blur effect throughout the UITableView, I had to set the entire thing's background color (including UITableViewCells and viewForHeaderInSection) to `UIColor.clearColor()`. The obvious problem (that I can't solve) is that when I scroll up, the text of the UITableViewCell will scroll under the clear background of the viewForHeaderInSection and both text will overlap. Here's a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5gJj4.jpg).

Any thoughts on how I can prevent the UITableViewCell from scrolling under the viewForHeaderInSection? I was playing around with the UITableView's contentInsets but that changes the entire UITableView, not just the UITableViewCell sections. Thx in advance...

Answer (score 1):

1) Select the tableview in storyboard.

2) Select attribute inspector.

3) Change the style from plain to grouped.

Comment: Sure, that fixes the overlap, but when I set `tableView.style = .Grouped`, the Header scrolls up with the tableView (so the Header doesn't stick at the top). I was hoping there was a compromise between the two...